# typererror: .push is not a function

Tags: node.js

Im trying to split a string into args and subargs and return it in an object, but then im getting the error...
Here is my code:

```
 function subargs(subargs) {
  var argargs = {};
  for (var i = 0; i <= subargs.length; i++) {
    if(subargs[i].indexOf(':') > -1) {
      var arg = subargs[i].slice(0, subargs[i].indexOf(':'))
      subargs[i].slice(subargs[i].indexOf(':') + 1, subargs[i].length)
      argargs.push(`["arg":${arg},"subarg":${subargs}]`);
      console.log(arg);
      console.log(subargs);
    }
  };
  return argargs;
}
```

Comment: `var argargs = {};` so it's an object, not an array. You can only `.push` to an array

Answer (score -2):

var argargs = {}; so it's an object, not an array. You can only .push to an array –  says `CertainPerformance` above

Comment: Do you know how I can push into the object?

Comment: you can simply do this to push to an object, `obj[key] = value`

Comment: why have you simply copy pasted some one else's comment as a solution?

Comment: you can do assignment like `argargs['key'] = value`. It's not an array so you have to give the value a key.

Comment: It's otherone's comment, not an answer

Comment: And what should i replace key with?

Comment: The key is a key that you use to reference later. You CAN use the index as a key as well. and the quotes `'key'` - it's a must.

Comment: How do I create a key?